# Excel: Avoid complicated formulas when comparing data in different excel workbooks

Tags: excel

When I write a formula to compare data in different workbooks, the formulas looks very cluttered since each time I reference a value in a different workbook, the entire name of the workbook appears in the formula. Is there a way to assign an alias to the workbook name so the formula is more readable?

Comment: is the other workbook closed or open?

Comment: see [`this`](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/)

Comment: The other workbook is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to store the path to the workbook in bits(*separate cells*)

using variables(Text in Cells) in book1 type:

```
A1 = book2
A2 = Sheet1
A3 = A1
```

Now go to any empty cell in *book1* and type the formula

```
=INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]"&A2&"'!"&A3)
```

The `Indirect()` pulls values from the Cells and replaces them creating a string which in the end is equal to `=[Book2.xlsm]Sheet1!A1`

So, instead of hard-coding the names of other opened workbooks, sheets, or ranges you can use values you entered in any other cell in your book1.

Now if you were to compare the value against some other cell from the other book, replace the `A3` with the actual value or change the `A3` from `A1` to some other cell

There is a downside to the `=INDIRECT()` function. It does NOT work with closed workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named range to refer to a different workbook.

Just add a named range as normal and enter:

```
=[WorkbookName]Sheetname!Range
```

eg

```
=[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10
```

You can then use this in formulas that take ranges, to refer to an individual value can be trickier and you'd need to use lookup/index.